# codeigniter will not show info from database

Tags: codeigniter, model, view, controller, foreach

Hello all i have a problem that my information is not being sendt to my view file.

it says: Message: Undefined variable: queryWall

my controller is this

```
function wallShow() 
 {
  $this->load->model('profil_model');
  $data['queryWall'] = $this->profil_model->wallGet($this->uri->segment(3));


  $data['content'] = 'profil_view';
  $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
 }
```

my model:

```
function wallGet($name)
 {
  $this->db->select('profileName', 'wallComment');
  $this->db->where('profileName', $name);
  $queryWall = $this->db->get('profileWall');

  if($queryWall->num_rows() > 0)
  {
   return $queryWall->result();
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }
```

and my view file

```
 <?php 
 if(!isset($queryWall)):
  foreach ($queryWall as $wall):
   echo $wall->wallComment;
  endforeach;
 endif;
 ?>
```

Comment: Try to print out the result of your query in your model method... Try <code>$queryWall->result()</code> in wallGet($name) function, to see if is any data selected

Comment: okay i have try to echo it out and i only got Array , so there is nothing in it :S, and i have try this $this->db->where('profileName', '123'); and i KNOW there is something in the database :S

Comment: I'm assuming that, in your template view, that you are making a call to a subview called "profile-view". are you passing $data or $queryWall to that sub view?  maybe you can add this part of your template view to your question so we can better help.

Answer (score 4):

Even if everything is fine, you'll keep getting this error since you are using the `queryWall` variable whenever it's **NOT** defined!

```
if(!isset($queryWall))
```

It should be:

```
if(isset($queryWall))
```

But since you are passing the conditional check, then I suppose you have something wrong with your model OR URI segment.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the correct syntax for

```
$this->db->select('profileName', 'wallComment');
```

Adjust it to this:

```
$this->db->select('profileName,wallComment');
```

then also enable the out profiler to verify your query is being written correctly by the database class.  In your controller, enable the profiler:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(true);
```

This can be inserted anywhere in the controller function.

I agree with ifaour about making sure your if statement is what you meant it to be.

Comment: +1 for catching the *2nd* bug in his code! so basically my answer and yours should solve his question.

Comment: how do i need $this->output->enable_profiler(true);, and i have made the change and it still not showing anything :S

Comment: Read the documentation for the output class for a full explanation of the profiler, and how to use it. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html.  What does the query look like from the profiler report?

Comment: nothing change it still says Undefined variable: queryWall :S

Comment: see my comment on your question above